# Transfer multi selected items from ListBox to another ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I would like to know how to move the items I have selected from left `ListBox` to the right `ListBox`? I tried to search but I've only seen moving the single item or all items from one `ListBox` to another.

Comment: Which technology? WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET? ...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all items of the listbox, check each item if it is selected and transfer that item to the other listbox

```
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items.Where(li=>li.Selected))
{
  // Move item to the other Listbox (You already have the code for this as you mentioned)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set the `Listbox`'s [`SelectionMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `Multiple`:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
```

Then:

```
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected))
{
    ListBox2.Items.Add(item);
}
```

In `ListBox1` select multiple items by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key then by clicking the button it should transfer multi selected items to `ListBox2`.

Answer (score 0):

I already have solution on my problem:

```
foreach (ListItem item in listbox1.Items)
{
  if (item.Selected == true)
  {
    listbox2.Items.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well your answer is exactly equivalent to mine just mine is linq version of this. Why did you try to post a new answer instead of accepting one the posted answer!?